# Determine Database Type (Oracle, SQL Server or Other)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, delphi

I have an application which connects to a Database, which can be Oracle, SQL Server or some other database.

I run the following code in the AfterConnect Event of the ADO Connection to determine the database type

```
    //establish type of database
  with qTableDefinition do begin
    //ORACLE
    Close;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL');
    try
      Open;
      DatabaseType := dtOracle;
    except
      //SQL Server
      Close;
      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('SELECT GETDATE() ');
      try
        Open;
        DatabaseType := dtSQL;
      except
        DatabaseType := dtOther;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

It tries to open a query using Oracle syntax, on success the database type is flagged as dtOracle.
If an exception occurs, it then tries a query using SQL Server syntax. This has been working fine up till recently.  It now throws up an Error message 'Invalid object name 'Dual'`, when the database is SQL Server.  The exception then gets passed to the next stage of the procedure, which works as expected.

I don't understand why it is suddenly showing an error message, instead of going to the exception straight away?

Comment: What **exact** query triggers the 'Invalid obect name 'Dual' ' exception?

Comment: Are you sure you can see this exception when running the application without debugger attached? If you run it from IDE with debugger (and 'Stop on Delphi exceptions' option enabled) it's normal to see exceptions even though they are correctly caught and handled.

Comment: Yes @BrakNicku, I have tried running it when the IDE is not running, and I still get the same error message.

Comment: @MartynA, it's the 'SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL' query.  If the database is not ORACLE then there is no DUAL table and the SYSDATE syntax is not applicable either.  I am using this exception to eliminate ORACLE as the database type.  It's just that I do not want the exception to be shown to the user.

Comment: This strategy is flaky. Someone may have created the `DUAL` table in another database or someone may have implemented the `GETDATE()` function as well. Get the database product name and version from the connection metadata.

Comment: Don't you need to configure the DBMS-specific driver you use before even opening the ADO connection? It seems to be you could leverage that info in your code instead of attempting various queries to identify the DBMS.

Comment: @TheImpaler, it is a specific database which comes in one of 3 versions, so I know it will be identified by my strategy.  However, could you clarify what you mean by the connection metadata (it is not something I am familiar with, and could it be an alternative solution to my problem?)

Comment: @DanGuzman. no I don't d any configuration of the ADO connection, it is provided as an ODBC connection string

Comment: Then parse the connection string to find out which database is being used instead.

Comment: I've amended the code to get the Database Type from the user when they enter the connection string.  However, that still does not answer the original question of why the Exception was producing an error message instead of just passing the exception to the exception handler